# How to project only subdocument matching query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following documents:

```
{ "id" : 1, "widgets" : [ { "name" : "foo", quantity: 1 }, { "name" : "bar", quantity: 3 } ] },
{ "id" : 2, "widgets" : [ { "name" : "baz", quantity: 2 } ] }
```

i would like to return the widget subdocument matching **id 1** and **name bar**, but I only want to return that widget so result should return:

```
{ "name" : "bar", quantity: 3 }
```

I cannot seem to find a projection to fulfil this scenario without looking into the aggregation operator `$filter` which can be costly

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                id: 1,
                widgets: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        name: 'bar'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$widgets",
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $match: {
                'widgets.name': 'bar'
            }
        },

        // Stage 5
        {
            $project: {
                widgets: 1
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to play with `aggregate` then cool. This is the way I would've done it.

```
db.products.aggregate([
     { $unwind : "$widgets"},
     { $match : {"id" : 1 , "widgets.name" : "bar"}},
     { $addFields: {name: "$widgets.name" ,quantity: "$widgets.quantity"}}, 
     { $project : {widgets : 0, _id : 0, id : 0}}

])
```

Now what's happening here is

1. Unwind Collection
2. Use filter
3. Add fields you want to show
4. hide everything else

That pretty much servers your query

Thanks